# PHP using incorrect time

Tags: php, date, ubuntu, timezone

Sorry if I have posted this in the wrong place as not sure if it's more php/super user question

I am having a bit of trouble getting PHP to use the correct timezone. It's always off by an hour. Instead of it saying 6:00pm for example, it will say 5:00pm

I have tried
Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and change the timezone to Europe/London
Changing `date.timezone` in php.ini to Europe/London
Running `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org` and `ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com` and also restarting apache, but not having any luck, not too sure what to do now

Any ideas?

Comment: So what actual code are you using?

Comment: Tried using date('d/m/Y') and also gmdate('d/m/Y') but the results the same.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Okay so AbraCadaver's links worked but surerly changing the default in php.ini would sort that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php.ini file change this variable `date.timezone` or in your php script use `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");`

Comment: I changed it in php.ini, but that doesn't work. For some reason it works with that php function though.

Comment: Any change in php.ini file it's required restart Apache. Can you try this like `date.timezone=Europe/London` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to set your timezone using PHP here is the piece of code that will give you correct output:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
```